# What are examples in java to show three ways to access an object?

Tags: java, oop

I am working on an assignment for my object-oriented class and came across a concept that I am having a hard time visualizing and trying to implement. So we learned about three different ways to access objects in java which are

> • By Composition (object contains a data member which itself is an object)
>
> • By Parameter Passing (passing of an object to a method of a
>    given object)
>
> • By Local Declaration (object declared within a method
>   of a given object)

I have tried to create one for the parameter passing which the example I created was this:

```
Temperature tempsF = new Temperature(32.6, 'F');
```

Which basically calls the object from the Temperature class and the we pass the values in the parameters of the object. 
The other ones I don't have a clue on how to generate an example of.

Comment: That's a weird way to put it. I wouldn't call any of those things "access".

Comment: How would you describe it? Maybe that's why I am having a hard time creating examples lol

Comment: Interestingly, your attempt to "access" an object (probably better described as gaining a *reference* to an object) using method parameters failed as your two parameters are both *primitive* type -- no objects are being passed here. Change at least once to a non-primitive reference type.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so you mean `Temperature tempsF = new Temperature(32.6, farhrenheit);` farhrenheit is the reference type that I am using but would that work?

Comment: Your *parameters* are both primitives, a double and a char, and if you're trying to access a reference to an object via a parameter, this won't work as an example. Please read up on "object" and "reference" to understand these key concepts as they are key to your understanding your assignment and solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has classes that consist of three things: constructors, fields, and methods (and some other things, such as other classes). Fields are variables where primitive values or objects can be stored, and methods are simply functions. Fields and methods can be `static`. An object is created when a constructor of the class is called and is given a copy of all the non-static fields and methods in the class.

Our object can thus "access" another object in three different ways:

- by having another object in one of its fields (composition)
- by receiving another object as a parameter to one of its methods (parameter passing)
- by creating another object inside one of its methods (local declaration)

An example class would be

```
class Person {
    String name;
    boolean alive;

    Person(String _name) {
        name = _name;
        alive = true;
    }

    void kill(Person anotherPerson) {
        anotherPerson.die();
    }

    void createAndKill() {
        Person newPerson = new Person("John Doe");
        newPerson.kill();
    }

    void die() {
        alive = false;
    }
}
```

An object of type `Person` has access to another object through

- composition by having an object of type `String` as a field
- parameter passing by someone calling `kill()`, which takes another `Person` object as a parameter
- local declaration by someone calling `createAndKill()` in which a new object of type `Person` will be created (and ruthlessly killed)

Comment: Awesome example! this makes so much sense, so basically these are different ways to access objects within the class, I feel like I was over complicating it -_-.